# String initialization fails: "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Tags: c++

I have two diffrent samples:

```
std::string* to_return = new std::string("I love"  + _name + " so much!");
```

And:

```
std::string* to_return = new std::string("I love"  + "Martin" + " so much!");
```

The first sample, illustrates initialization when trying to add another simple string object named "_name".
At the secons example, I just connect three differents strings...

The Error appear when trying to make the second sample:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: Having `std::string` on the heap is simply a design mistake.

Comment: You can only concatenate with `std::string` objects. String literals like `"stuff"` are not `std::string` objects. One of them needs to be a `std::string` for it to work.

Comment: std::cout<<"str"+i+"std" fails as OP but std::cout<<"str"+i works...another example of simple operation need ugly code in C++. To be specific I need std::cout<<(b?"":("str"+i+"str"))<<... and the ugly code that works is std::cout<<(b?"":("str"+std::string(i)+"str"))<<...

Comment: Found that "str"+i returns a char* pointer that is i char offset from the begin of "str"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`"I love"  + _name + " so much!"` evaluates to a `std::string` since that class contains overloaded `+` operators to `const char*` on both sides, and `_name` is a `std::string` instance.

But the compiler cannot use any overloaded `+` for `"I love"  + "Martin" + " so much!"` as these are simply built-int `const char[]` literals for which `+` is invalid, so compilation fails.

`std::string() + "I love"  + "Martin" + " so much!"`, however would work, as would resorting to C-style compile-time concatenation:

`std::string("I love" "Martin" " so much!");`

---

<sup>Finally, Martin might appreciate the message even more if there was a space after `"love"`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed now that I can concatenate char like 'j' instead of the string object, with the pluse operator. How it can be?

Comment: @fdwfgwdfwdfv: You're actually doing *pointer arithmetic* in that case, with possibly terrible results. That's another question in itself.

Answer (score 2):

"string" is not a `std::string` object, it's just a pointer to chars (`char*`). If you try to use `operator+` on pointers, nothing good typically happens.

To concatenate several old-style strings, it's a good idea to convert one of them to `std::string` explicitly:

```
std::string s = std::string("str") + "ing";
```

Also, since `c++14` you can use [literal "s"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to convert c-style string to `std::string`:

```
auto s = "string"s; // has type std::string and contains data "string"
```

Answer (score 1):

A string literal is a `const char[(whatever)]`, and concatenation of a `const char[(whatever)]` is not allowed in C++.

Answer (score 0):

As long as one of the arguments to operator+ is a `std::string`, the compiler will figure it out without the use of brackets:

```
#include <string>

std::string expressAffectionFor(const std::string& name)
{
    auto to_return = "I love"  + name + " so much!";  
    return to_return;
}
```

When `name` is a pointer to (possibly const) chars, the expression has no sensible meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The strings `"I love"`, `"Martin"` and `" so much!"` are of type `const char*`. I presume that `_name` is of type `std::string`.

The `+` operator is not defined for two `const char*`, but it is defined for one `const char*` and one `std::string`.

You need to convert at least one of the `const char*` objects to `std::string` prior using `+`. Since `+` associates from right to left, use either the last or the second but last object:

`std::string* to_return = new std::string("I love"  + "Martin" + std::string(" so much!"));`

Comment: No, strictly they are `const char[<length>]`. And you can apply `std::string` anywhere since `+` has overloads on "both sides".